# How to get horizontal scrolling of this kind?

Tags: html, css

How to achieve partial horizontal scrolling?
As given in the fiddle, the scrollbar is full 100% as a result of which i cannot see the last few elements.
I have an input box of a set width, which has to be positioned like given. But i want the scrollbar to end just before the input box. 
https://jsfiddle.net/77ubr2ht/

format of html is like -

```
<ul>
<li></li>....<li></li>
<input type="text">
</ul>
```

Comment: try this https://jsfiddle.net/nxs5pa1q/

Comment: @Kishan - user would have to scroll to see the input box. that should be fixed to the right of the main ul

Answer (score 0):

Try this change in css

```
ul {
    width: 430px;
    float:left;
    margin:0;
}
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/hsy1zy5y/) or input box in scroller [input in scroller](https://jsfiddle.net/nxs5pa1q/)

change in css

```
#x {
background: cyan;
position:relative;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I did a few changes to it.

https://jsfiddle.net/77ubr2ht/1/

When you use `position: fixed` in your input field, you effectively remove the element from the normal page flow and so other elements can't interact with it. I also set the width of the scroll area to `max-width: 100%`. You had a hardcoded width which would prevent that element from expanding to the page length.

Comment: In your solution, the input box is positioned on top. I want the input box part of the "ul" and scrollbar scroll up to 75-80% of the width(just before the input box)

Answer (score 0):

I change your html structure and use `css calc`.

[Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/77ubr2ht/6/)

Comment: HTML cannot be changed :( I just want to tweak the css and if necessary add jquery/JS

Comment: @anandpatil Is it possible to wrap all `li`s within a `div`:

Comment: @anandpatil The jsfiddle is updated, please check it.

Answer (score 0):

Please check this working fiddle. Hope it will be what you are expecting.

```css
div {
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    border: 2px solid pink;
    margin-top: 25px;
}
li {
    display: inline-block;
    border:1px solid green;
}

ul {
    width: 75%;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    overflow-x: auto;
    float: left;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0px;
}

#x {
    float: left;
    background: cyan;
}
```

```html
<div>
<ul>
<li>oranges</li>
<li>apple</li>
<li>grapes</li>
<li>oranges</li>
<li>apple</li>
<li>grapes</li>
    <li>oranges</li>
<li>apple</li>
<li>grapes</li>
    <li>oranges</li>
<li>apple</li>
<li>grapes</li>
    <li>oranges</li>
<li>apple</li>
<li>grapes</li>
    <li>oranges</li>
<li>apple</li>
<li>grapes</li>
    <li>oranges</li>
<li>apple</li>
<li>grapes</li>
    <li>oranges</li>
<li>apple</li>
<li>grapes</li>

</ul>
<input type="text" placeholder="type something" id="x" />
    </div>
```

Comment: Thanks! the HTML cannot be changed. I had tried this earlier :)

Comment: Can you use some script do wrap ul with a div? then it will work right.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will help. I added a class.

```
<ul>
    <li>oranges</li>
    <li>apple</li>
    <li>grapes</li>
    <li>oranges</li>
    <li>apple</li>
    <li>grapes</li>
    <li>oranges</li>
    <li>apple</li>
    <li>grapes</li>
    <li>oranges</li>
    <li>apple</li>
    <li>grapes</li>
    <li>oranges</li>
    <li>apple</li>
    <li>grapes</li>
    <li>oranges</li>
    <li>apple</li>
    <li>grapes</li>
    <li>oranges</li>
    <li>apple</li>
    <li>grapes</li>
    <li>oranges</li>
    <li>apple</li>
    <li>grapes</li>
    <li class="test"><input type="text" placeholder="type something" id="x"></li> 
</ul>
```

I also added this CSS:

```
.test{
    display: block;
    margin-top: 10px;
}
```